# Render TreeView in React using Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to create a Tree View using Material UI React JS. But the catch is that the JSON in tree view has pre-defined structure. To view the structure please follow the link

https://codesandbox.io/s/1slq1

And, I am getting the JSON from an API in completely different format with array of Objects & more. Below is the example of JSON response from API

```
[{
   "order":123,
   "date" : 24-2-2020,
   "item":{
     "itemName" : "Item 01",
     "price" : 120,
     "charges" :[
      {
         "charge01" : "Delivery",
         "amount" : 110
      },
      {
         "charge02" : "Taxes",
         "amount" : 10
      }
    ],
     "otherDetails" : [
       {
            "data" : "somedata"
       }
    ]
   }
}]
```

I need to create a function where above JSON is converted to pre-defined Material UI TreeView JSON. Below is the code what I have tried but no success :

```
const renderTreeData = (dataItem: any) => {
  if (typeof (dataItem) == "object") {
    for (var key in dataItem) {
        return {
            id:key,
           name: dataItem[key].toString(),
           children: renderTreeData(dataItem[key])
        }
    }
   }   
    return renderData;
  }
```

Below is the screenshot of what is required:

[image]

Comment: need to try recursive function, but i m not that good in typescript or javascript

Comment: can you also add how you visualize your output for your data structure.. like which is the parent.. which is the child and their child.. etc

Comment: @Panther I have added an screenshot within the question

Comment: Check this out and see how it helps you https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nnje0?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @Panther: thanks for the code, but my requirement is dynamic function, because the JSON response will be dynamic, like Other info can have multiple child.

Comment: It cannot be made dynamic at some places.. as you can see the charges.. where in each object has a diff key named `charge01`, `charge02`.etc.. which needs to be formated in a diff way. The rest is good to be dynamic i hope

Comment: Checkout the same link. Thats the much dynamic. For array, the name of the tree should be identified. hope you can find a logic as per ur requirement and add it. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nnje0?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @Panther :  we can make charge child key same.. if requried

Comment: @Panther i will try the code..  thanks

Comment: @Panther: getting error on line no 89 for renderTree, I have edited & assign types to function. Below is the error

Argument of type '(nodes: { id: string; name: string; children: any[]; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { id: string; name: string; children: void; }, index: number, array: { id: string; name: string; children: void; }[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'nodes' and 'value' are incompatible.